# Numerical integration degree of precision

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

> For a smooth function $f$ we have the integral$$\int^1_{-1} f(x) dx,$$Consider the numerical scheme that approximates this integral as$$\int^1_{-1} f(x)dx \approx w_1 f\left( \frac{-1}{2} \right) + w_2 f \left( \frac{1}{3} \right).$$ Is the method exact for $f(x)=x^2$? What does this say about its degree of precision?

**Attempt:**

I have already worked out the weights $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that the method is exact for functions $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x:$

$$f(x)=1: \ \int^1_{-1} 1 dx = 2$$

$$\therefore w_1+w_2 = 2 \tag{1}$$

$$f(x)=1: \ \int^1_{-1} x dx = 0$$

$$\therefore \frac{-1}{2} w_1+ \frac{1}{3} w_2 = 0 \tag{2}$$

Solving the **(1)** and **(2)**, we get $w_1 = 12/15,$ and $w_2 = 6/5.$ Hence for $x^2$ we get:

$$\approx  \frac{12}{15}\left( \frac{-1}{2} \right)^2+ \frac{6}{5} \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{3}$$

So how does this show if the method is exact for $f(x)=x^2$? And what is the degree of precision?

Comment: $w_1=\frac 4 5$ and $w_2=\frac 6 5$. You solved the system incorrectly.

Comment: $\frac{12}{15} = \frac{4}{5}.$

Comment: Oh...Sorry! I thought it said $\frac{12}{5}$. Also, I don't know much about numerical analysis, but this is not exact because $\int_{-1}^1 x^2 \ dx=\frac {1^3}{3}-\frac{(-1)^3}{3}=\frac 2 3 \neq \frac 1 3$. I don't know what the "degree of precision" is, though.